# Recuperar `staged changes` despues de un git reset -hard

Tags: git

Estaba viendo una mosca, y de pronto decidí cambiar de rama a `desarrollo`. Actualmente estaba en una subrama de `desarrollo` trabajando en una nueva función. Esta nueva rama tenía cambios `staged` (no se cual seria la traduccion correcta) y otros que no lo estaban. Cuando hago el cambio de rama a `desarrollo` me pide que haga un reset al `head` para sincronizar los datos remotos y por ende borre mi trabajo en proceso (la mosca ya había desaparecido para ese entonces... :`S   )

Es posible recuperar estos datos?. Debería haber hecho un `stash` para no perder los datos pero no lo hice así.

Mis ramas estaban de esta manera

```
/master
    /desarrollo
         /trabajoActual
```

Todo el problema surge al sincronizar los datos remotos nuevos con `desarrollo`.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm esta peliagudo.

Puedes probar usando

```
git fsck --lost-found
```

Te debería dejar unos commits en `.git/lost-found/` y puedes usar `git show <fichero>` para encontrar esos cambios.

suerte